# Applying dataframe row values to a column in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

I've cut up an ugly csv file to a reasonable form. I'm left with a row of values in the dataframe that I need to apply to other columns.

Each region (NA, SA, Eur) has different sectors (energy, food, etc) that have market values (1,2,3...etc). I want to group the market values to the sectors and repeat them through.

Right now it looks like:

```
'Left over header to be discarded' |  Market   |       1       |         2     |     3         |....
North America                      |   Energy  |  valueenergy1 |  valueenergy2 |   valueenergy3 |...
North America                      |   Food    |  valuefood1   |   valuefood2  |   valuefood3    |...
North America                      |   Shelter |      .
South America                      |   Energy  |      .
South America                      |   Food    |      .
Europe                             |   Energy  |  valueenergy1  |..
Europe                             |   Food    |  valuefood1    |..
Europe                             |   Shelter |  valueshelter1 |..
.
.
```

I've stored the row as a list with .values.tolist() and removed it from the dataframe to apply it; I'm just not sure how to apply it. I want to have an output that looks like:

```
    North America          |     1      |   Energy  | valueenergy1 | 
    South America          |     1      |   Energy  | valueenergy1 |
    Europe                 |     1      |   Energy  | valueenergy1 |
        .
        .
    North America          |     2      |   Food    | valuefood2   | 
    South America          |     2      |   Food    | valuefood2   | 
    Europe                 |     2      |   Energy  | valueenergy2 |
       .
       .
    North America          |     3      |   Food    | valuefood3   | 
    South America          |     3      |   Food    | valuefood3   | 
    Europe                 |     3      |   Shelter | valuehelter3 |
```